# C++ Selection Sort

Tags: c++, sorting

```
void sortSellersbyId (Seller sellerArray[], int size){
Seller small = sellerArray[0];
for (int x = 0; x < size; x++){
  for (int y = 1; y < size; y++){
    if (sellerArray[y].sellerId < sellerArray[x].sellerId){
      small = sellerArray[y];
      sellerArray[y] = sellerArray[x];
      sellerArray[x] = small;
      }
  }
}
}
```

I'm trying to use selection sort to put some values in ascending order. For some reason the [0] value is correct but everything else is sorted in descending order when I print all the values. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

*edit*

Thanks to whoever answered my question (and then instantly deleted it for some reason). This is my first time implementing any kind of sort so I was just trying to figure it out logically and it obviously went poorly.

I got close but setting y = 1 was causing redundant checking that was also reverse switching my values. Setting y = x + 1 in my 2nd for loop makes the loop ignore the values that have already been sorted. The posted solution also had x < size - 1 in my first loop since the last value doesn't need to be sorted. Hopefully those explanations are correct. Here is the new output that works.

```
void sortSellersbyId (Seller sellerArray[], int size){
Seller small = sellerArray[0];
for (int x = 0; x < size - 1; x++){
  for (int y = x + 1; y < size; y++){
    if (sellerArray[y].sellerId < sellerArray[x].sellerId){
      small = sellerArray[y];
      sellerArray[y] = sellerArray[x];
      sellerArray[x] = small;
      }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: This looks like a bubble sort with incorrect loop definition. X should stop at < size-1 and y should start at x+1

Comment: @mah it would be more "incorrect" (if there is such a thing; an infinite no. of incorrect algorithms, right?) than that. Bubblesort continually *decrements* the *stopping* point; not continually *increments* the *starting* point. And it never compares non-adjacent elements.

Comment: @WhozCraig I can accept that there is more than one (correct) algorithm (and as you say, infinite incorrect ones :) for a bubble sort, but `for (i = 0; i < size-1; i++) for (j = i+1; j < size; j++)` is definitely a valid bubble sort. Each run of the inner loop "bubbles" the i element to its proper position (determined by the sense of the pre-swap comparison) for the bubble sort's O(n^2) operation.

Comment: @mah if moving an element is considered "bubbling" it, then all sorts are bubblesort. You just described (and the loop change made by the OP then-authored) [*selection sort*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). Bubblesort passes over the sequence swapping adjacent elements as needed until the end of the sequence, when the "winner" is in the last slot and all the others have "moved" toward their final destination. The last slot stopping point is decremented with each pass. If *any* pass yields no swaps, the algorithm terminates. unlike selection sort....

Comment: ... bubblesort has best-case (already sorted sequence) of O(n).